# ASP.NET WebMatrix After form post page reload Error?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, browser, webmatrix

I'm using ASP.NET Webmatrix and trying to load more data from SQL Database by Form Post request.

By default I have 2 Results and When I click the Load More Button each time the result increases by +2.

[image]

Everything is working fine. !But When I'm trying to reload my page, browser shows error.

[image]

Even if my form is already posted but browser is still showing for Resubmission error. How can I remove this error? Plz Help Me! & Here is my code:

```
**.cshtml**
@{
    var rowsNumb = 2;
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    if (IsPost){
        rowsNumb = Request["lastRec"].AsInt() + 2;
    }else{}
    var maxRecs = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT([Product Id]) FROM Products");
    var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY [Product Id] 
                OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS  ONLY";
    rowsNumb = (rowsNumb > maxRecs ? maxRecs : rowsNumb);
    var result = db.Query(sql, rowsNumb);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            @foreach(var row in result){
                <tr>
                    <td>@row["Product Name"]</td>
                    <td>@row["English Name"]</td>
                    <td>@row["Unit Price"]</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lastRec" value="@rowsNumb"/>
            <button type="submit">Load More</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Erm, that's not an "error", that's normal browser information.  If the page you're on has been loaded with POST data, then refreshing the page requires that POST data to be sent again (otherwise there's a high chance it won't work).  Not a lot you're going to be able to do about it

Comment: Isn't there any way or any other method to accomplish this without post a request?

Comment: Not really... ASP.NET relies on POST information for post-back to work correctly

Comment: Slight clarification to previous comment - if you need to work with POSTed information, in some fashion, then it's all/any platform. Above isn't "WebForms" and doesn't have _inherent_ dependency on `postback` - even though that is in fact what is going on...aka "bare metal" way. Hth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Its not Error

This is not an error in Browser, or your code. It is just the question by Browser when it wants to ask the user whether the user wants to load the page with the very same data that he passed on previous time. No error!

#### Reasons for this

That is because you're getting the data by submitting the form. So it behaves like you want to get the data againt that was achieved by passing on some data, like username etc. That is why it asks for this dialog.

```
<button type="submit">Load More</button>
```

The above button is the reason for this.

What you can do, is to use `action` and forward yourself to a new page where you will use the `Response.Redirect()` to the back page with an extra parameter, maybe a User Friendly like `www.example.com/products?page=2`. In the HTML you won't write the page = 2 or anything. But it would denote that the page is new and the page **was not load** using a POST request.

This way, you won't get the dialog again. Untill you use the submit button to load the content of the page, you will get this box.

#### A work around

There is another alternate way of doing this. Which is using jQuery (I know I know jQuery always is not the only function, but) and removing the `type="submit"` attribute. For example, the HTML would be

```
<button id="submit">Load More</button>
```

The jQuery to handle this code would be

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
   // either use ajax to load the content and add it, or
   // use window.location() to move to the next page and
   // come back to this page using Response.Redirect();
}
```

[Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(v=vs.90).aspx) method of ASP.NET

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from jQuery API

#### Remove the `if(IsPost)` block

```
if (IsPost) { 
   rowsNumb = Request["lastRec"].AsInt() + 2;
   Response.Redirect("~/Default?v2");
}
```

This code block would only execute when there is a Header to denote the request was post (the request is post if the form submitted has `method="post"`). So using my idea won't work if you're having that block.

Remove the condition and execute it.

```
rowsNumb = Request["lastRec"].AsInt() + 2;
Response.Redirect("~/Default?v2");
```

Just this, this would update the variable by 2 and then provide the result again. POST would only execute if the request is made through form and has the method set to post. That is also the point where the *error* generates in your UI.

#### Entire code for you

```
@{
    var rowsNumb = 2;
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    rowsNumb = Request["lastRec"].AsInt() + 2;
    // no need for else block since there is no code there
    var maxRecs = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT([Product Id]) FROM Products");
    var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY [Product Id] 
            OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS  ONLY";
    rowsNumb = (rowsNumb > maxRecs ? maxRecs : rowsNumb);
    var result = db.Query(sql, rowsNumb);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            @foreach(var row in result){
                <tr>
                    <td>@row["Product Name"]</td>
                    <td>@row["English Name"]</td>
                    <td>@row["Unit Price"]</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <a href="~/page?lastRec=@rowsNumb">Load More</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I had to write the code the above would have been the code it self. This code is all that you need. It would reload the page and would update the content and so on. Without using the `POST` request.

Comment: Not Working? `if (IsPost){rowsNumb = Request["lastRec"].AsInt() + 2;{Response.Redirect("~/Default?v2");}}`

Comment: @MaryMelody I have explained that behaviour for you in the last paragraph. Hopefully you understood that part and the error in your UI along with the method of the form. If you need more, comment here!

Comment: There is a issue using `Response.Redirect("~/Default?v2");` I'm getting a blank page that have `~/Default?v2` in the last.

Comment: It's Working now... after removing <form method="post"> to <form>. Thanks:)

Comment: Yes, I have added the entire code and explained it too. :) Good luck!

Comment: YUP:) You're a genius!

Comment: Nope, just a developer like you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code on the server side.
This will refresh the page.
Even you can change the refresh page timing.

```
Response.AppendHeader("refresh", "2");
```